# Animate svg image: got paths animated, but not the ellipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I am trying to animate an svg image. It does animate all the paths, but it does not animate my ellipse which looks like this:

```
<ellipse id="Oval-1" fill="#0B619B" opacity="0.141849347" cx="929.5" cy="94.5" rx="94.5" ry="94.5"></ellipse>
```

why could this be?
I am using [this javascript library (jquery-drawsvg)](http://leocs.me/jquery-drawsvg) and the code looks like this:

```
var $svg = $('svg').drawsvg();
$svg.drawsvg('animate');
```

- so it's quite simple. and it does work for the paths in my svg file.but i do not understand why the ellipse is not being drawn.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence on the plugin's page is very clear:

> This plugin uses the jQuery built-in animation engine to transition the stroke on every *path* inside the selected *svg* element, using stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset properties.

You don't have a `<path>` here, you have an `<ellipse>` (or should I say "circle"?). The plugin just works with **paths**.

One alternative is converting the ellipse to a path, then using that path instead of the ellipse.

This is the path that corresponds to your ellipse:

```
<path id="Oval-1" fill="#0B619B" opacity="0.141849347" d="M835,94.5a94.5,94.5 0 1,0 189,0a94.5,94.5 0 1,0 -189,0"/>
```

Don't forget to set the `stroke` and the `stroke-width` in the above path.

Comment: This creates the image accordingly, but still does not animate it. Could you maybe recommend a (free) library which is able to animate ellipses and other shapes apart from paths?